# AppJS does not show Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, appjs

I have a situation where I want to open a website by clicking a desktop icon. I found AppJS to be the answer. I created an app with just a full window covering iframe. The only problem I am facing is, Unicode characters are not shown properly (all I see is boxes in place of text). I could not understand where should I look for. Please, give me some pointers. or maybe an alternative to fulfill the original purpose.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the website name?

Comment: @AshokShah http://rajeshmunat.in

Comment: seems fine to me. Just tested with new version of appjs. Will you please confirm at your end. Happy to help, thanks

Comment: Sure, let me see...